# When is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) dx$?

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

When is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) dx$?

Normally, we would need to take two different limits, but I am wondering if there is necessary and/or sufficient condition that the integral can be evaluated by taking the limit simultaneously. If so, is $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-kn}^n f(x) dx$$ for any $k > 0$?

More specifically, if we know that the integral converges, why can we conclude that $\int_\infty^\infty f(x) dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x) dx$?

Comment: If $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ exists, then it is equal to its Cauchy Principal Value.

Comment: @MarkViola thank you, could you elaborate more with justification?

Comment: What is the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f?.$

Comment: If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\,dx < \infty$, then it's true.  Also, the $L^1$ condition is equivalent to $\int_{-n}^n |f(x)|\,dx$ being bounded as a function of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F'(x)=f(x).$ Then using definitions, and the  FTC we can see

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx= \lim_{s\to\infty}\int_a^s f(x)dx +\lim_{t\to-\infty}\int_t^a f(x)dx$$

$$=\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)-F(a) +\lim_{t\to-\infty}F(a)-F(t)$$
$$=\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)-\lim_{t\to-\infty}F(t).$$

If these two limits exist, then it means that the result is finite, and in particular, it is well defined, and we don't need to evaluate these limits separately. Thus

$$\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)-\lim_{t\to-\infty}F(t)=\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)-F(-s).$$

It is only in this situation that the principal value is equal to the result of the improper integral (equality can only be discussed because it converges, after all!).

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds basic, but why does two limits existing imply we can take both limits altogether?

Comment: The reason is that these two limits do not influence each other. One limit applies to large positive values, the other to large negative values. Since there is no interaction, the two effects simply add up. That is what Chickenmancer demonstrates in his answer.